# Removing an item from an ArrayList where an element's string contains a certain string

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that I need to delete an element from.

I get an output like this:

```
ArrayList: [2062253<:>2, 2062254<:>242.0, 2062252<:>100]
```

I was to be able to delete `2062254<:>242.0`. I could just delete the item with a `.remove("2062254<:>242.0")` but the thing is that the string always changes. The only part of the string that doesn't change is the `54<:>`.

Is there a way to remove an element from an arraylist by using something like: `.contains("54<:>")`?

Maybe I could do an if check list this:

```
if (calList.contains("54<:>")) {
    //How can I get the index ID here? Remove this index from the arraylist
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go through the list and check each element:

```
Iterator<String> it = calList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  if (it.next().contains("54<:>")) {
    it.remove();
    // Add break; here if you want to remove just the first match.
  }
}
```